# How to update React and dependencies to a specific version?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have project with massive amount of dependencies. It uses react 16.8. I need to update React to a specific version: React: 17.0.2
How to do it automatically? I don't want to check each package if it is compatible with this version of React.
It seems all existing automatic methods update to the latest version only(npm-check-updates).

Answer (score 0):

To change the React version your project is using you need to run the following command
`npm install –save react@<version>`
, where `<version>` is a variable. You should substitute it for the desired version of React.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

This approach will help you, first you need to update your react version by doing the following command if you are running on old version of react.

```
npm i react@latest react-dom@latest
```

**Step 2:**

In next step you need to check for the updated versions of dependencies by following the below command (it will change the dependency versions in package.json):

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
```

**Step 3:**

use the below command to install the upadated node modules.

```
npm install
```